# MySQL - Select from 2 tables even the other table is empty

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables consisting of artists and tracks.

```
Artist
| id       | name           |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1        | John Doe       |
| 2        | Dave Wang      | 

Tracks
| id       | artist_id      | title          |
| -------- | -------------- | -------------- |
| 1        | 1              | Song 1         |
| 2        | 1              | Song 2         |
```

I tried

`SELECT a.name, b.title FROM Artist a, Tracks b WHERE a.id = b.artist_id`

It returns all the songs of John Doe.

Is there a way to add Dave Wang on the result even it's just null on the title?

For example result

| name | title |
| --- | --- |
| John Doe | Song 1 |
| John Doe | Song 2 |
| Dave Wang | *null* |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an explicit left join:

```sql
SELECT a.name, b.title
FROM Artist a
LEFT JOIN Tracks b
    ON a.id = b.artist_id;
```

As a side note, your current query is using the old school implicit join syntax.  The version I gave above is the correct way of writing the join.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query

**SELECT a.id, a.name,b.title FROM artist as a LEFT JOIN tracks as b on a.id = b.artist_id;**